# How to install Apache and DNSmasq tools, without Terminal

Tags: linux, debian, terminal, software-installation, zip

How can I install apache server and dnsmasq without using a terminal? Just downloading ZIP files and manually configuring them. The easiest is to install the installation tools from the command line, since the terminal sets up each file in its different directories. But I want to do it manually on Debian 11. I ask this question because on Windows I have configured Apache by downloading the ZIP and instead of storing it in Program Files, I store it elsewhere, and it will start successfully, but install Apache in Terminal , it is configured automatically, which by default is stored in the /etc/ folder, what I don't know is that if it doesn't open problems downloading the ZIP and starting the service, without the need to use the /etc/ folder.

Comment: Debian software is installed from .deb packages, not from ZIP files.   You may think you want to "do it manually", but I assure you that you really, really don't - especially if you don't even know the difference between .zip and .deb files.  Manually compiling and installing software like apache or dnsmasq is not a task for a novice, it takes a lot of knowledge, experience, and attention to detail.  Just install the packages with apt, either from the command line or a GUI interface like synaptic.

Comment: You want to try "_downloading ZIP files and configuring them manually_" but you also say "_without using a terminal_". (The terminal is simply a means to access a command line.) What is it you thinking of, that could let you configure something manually but without using the command line?

Answer (score 0):

Linux software is distributed, and installed, differently than Windows software.

With Windows, you may get a self-extracting ZIP file.

Instead, Linux software is distributed in package format: `.deb` for Debian, `.rpm` for Red Hat (RHEL / Fedora / CentOS and derivatives), etc. You don't get it in `.zip` file format. You can get the source code in a gzipped file, but this is meant for an install via source, which is really not recommended for neophytes (because of the difficulty, and also because software installed as such resides outside the package manager database and can lead to broken dependencies).

So, the proper way to install Apache - or whatever - is through the distro's package manager via command line or GUI.

The `/etc` directory you are mentioning is where Apache's (and other software's) config files are kept. One should not change that, as it will result in a broken system.